# How to solve "ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (73584, 15) instead."

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to python and machine learning.
I want to fit SVM to the training sets.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3)
clf=SVC(kernel='rbf')
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Then I got an error: `ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (73584, 15) instead.`

```py
x_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape
```

Output:

```
((73584, 37), (31536, 37), (73584, 15), (31536, 15))
```

So how should I fix this problem?
Would appreciate a lot if any advices.

---

Shape of `y`:

[image]

Examples of label `y` are:

[image]

Comment: This a fundamental issue. SVC requires y values to be 1d classification samples. It doesnt support multidimensional y values. Can you describe your dataset or problem for which you have multi-dimensional y values?

Comment: @NiteyaShah I am working on a project to perdict where leakages are in the pipeline using SVC and for y, it just represents leaking points in pipeline and I posted a picture showing the information of y, and for x, it contains pressure and flow values measured by sensors. Could you please explain how to fix this problem in more detail? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think the problem is that you haven't properly set an objective. What exactly is supposed to the outcome of ML model? My current guess is that for a set of pressure and flow values, it has to predict the leaking points? Because if it s then the problem type isn't classification but rather regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVM output is, for each data point, one class. Therefore, with 73584 data points of 37 features, your target needs to be a vector of 73584 classifications, each of which is a class number. Did you one-hot encode your output? You should undo that.

Comment: I am working on a project to perdict where leakages are in the pipeline using SVC and for y, it just represents leaking points in pipeline, and for x, it contains pressure and flow values measured by sensors. I did not one-hot encode my output. Could you please explain how to fix this problem in more detail?

Comment: @ZiyuanCai what are the 15D `y` vectors? Can you give me one example? Is it going to be full of zeros except for exactly one 1? A better description of `y` may help.

Comment: I have added two images above showing the information on y. Could you please check them? Thank you very much!

Comment: @ZiyuanCai Then this cannot be classified with SVC. Specifically, SVM classifies data into one of many classes, whereas your label doesn't show anything resembling classes. What do the numbers in `y` mean? In some rows they are all zeros, and in others they have numbers that doesn't seem too meaningful at first glance.

Comment: y means the amount of leakage in these 14 pipes at the different time point. So you mean SVC is not suitable for solving this problem ?

Comment: @ZiyuanCai Yes. Your problem is a regression problem, not classification. Try using SVR instead. Also, none of these will explicitly handle a time-series problem (which yours is).

Comment: thanks bro, from old sun* :) (hosjiu)